# count amount for sub code

Tags: mysql

### tab1

```
id    code   name
1001   0     palani
1002  1001   shanker
1003  1002   raghu
1004  1003   kabhir
1005  1003   vani
1006  1002   priya
```

### tab2

```
id  code  name  amount  tax
1   1002  b      100     1
2   1002  j      20      10
3   1003  jk     23      20
4   1004  jk     675     9 
5   1005  o      67       3 
6   1003  u      122      4
7   1003  o      98       1
8   1003  iu     98       1
9   1002  po     4        0.4
10  1005  pl     1        0.1  
12  1005  tf     1        0.1
24  1006  e      23       2.3
```

id 1001 see code 1001 corresponding id 1002

id 1002 see code 1002 corresponding id 1003,1006

id 1003 see code 1003 corresponding id 1004,1005

others no need

Result need like this

```
code   amount   tax
1001   124      11.4
1002   364      28.3
1003   744      12.2
```

Please send the mysql query for this

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a site that 'sends' code. Please stop asking similar questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

GROUP BY is your friend:

```
select tab1.id, sum (tab2.amount) amount, sum (tab2.tax) tax
from
tab1, tab2
where tab1.code = tab2.id
and tab1.id in (1001, 1002, 1003)
group by tab1.id
```

Comment: (1001, 1002, 1003) this are dynamic

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic? Does the user select these in a list? In this case, build your IN clause dynamically in a for loop or similar.

Answer (score 0):

This will get what you want from tab2

```
SELECT code, SUM(amount), SUM(tax) FROM tab GROUP BY code ORDER BY code
```

I can't see how tab1 fits into what you want

Comment: Tab1 seems to be some kind of translation table for ID -> Code (although the column naming is quite unfortunate)

Comment: @user363534, you're right I missed the group by off. fixed it now

Answer (score 0):

does it work (not tested)

```
select SUM(t2.amount) AS Amount,SUM(t2.tax) AS totalTax,t2.code FROM 
table2 t2
INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.code=t2.code
```